# Do we really need edition-specific tags for Twilight Imperium?

Tags: discussion, tags

Tonight I found a question about Twilight Imperium 2nd edition in the "untagged" bucket.  When I went to tag it [twilight-imperium-3rd-edn](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twilight-imperium-3rd-edn) came up, but nothing else.  So I created [twlight-imperium-2nd-edn](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twlight-imperium-2nd-edn), but the former only has 11 questions.  Can we just collapse on [twilight-imperium](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twilight-imperium), or are the editions sufficiently different that we need the separation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this. For now, we are trying hard to [avoid the can of worms](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/845/re-tag-for-warhammer-40k-questions/852) that is version tags, because it adds lots of complexity to tagging. We can revisit this question in due course if the pressure for versions mounts, and discuss the tradeoffs again then. But this example is not sufficient.

Both tags should be collapsed to [twilight-imperium](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twilight-imperium).